# Ошибка во время попытки установки nuget пакета

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Чего-то у меня последнее время сильно глючит работа с пакетами `nuget`. В Visual Studio с ошибками грузится список пакетов, а выбранный пакет не удается установить.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Refit.4.3.0' from source 'nuget.org'.
>   An error occurred while sending the request.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
>   Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение          0

Если же зайти на сайт и попытаться скачать оттуда, то появляется сообщение "Ошибка при установлении защищённого соединения". Это у меня одного так или у многих? Неужели это результат борьбы с телегой?

**P.S.**
Пришлось в обходную на виртуалке с Linux с соотв.настройками скачать пакет и установить так

```
PM> Install-Package refit -Source C:\Temp\
```

Comment: Видимо последствия "блокировки" Телеграма. Сегодня тоже обнаружил, что Nuget работает только под VPN.

Comment: Да, Nuget заблокирован: api.nuget.org (93.184.221.200). https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/5806

Comment: @Maxwell спасибо за отклик, а то я уж подумал, что это у меня одного так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Негодяи из РКН заблокировали ip адрес api.nuget.org
Единственный выход - настраивать VPN.
У меня это началось 17 апреля.